# Não consigo sincronizar a hora do meu relogio windows

Tags: windows, cmd, time, sistema-operacional, windows-10

Eu instalei o windows ontem(2019-08-16), e a hora do SO aparece 3 hrs a frente, eu tento sincronizar e nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Digito no CMD

```
>w32tm /resync /rediscover
Enviando comando resync para o computador local
O computador não sincronizou novamente porque não havia dados de hora
disponíveis.

>w32tm /resync
Enviando comando resync para o computador local
O computador não sincronizou novamente porque não havia dados de hora
disponíveis.
```

Eu andei dando um procurada e não encontrei nada que me ajudou a solucionar esse problema, acho que pode estar relacionado com o comando a baixo.

```
>w32tm /query /source
Local CMOS Clock
```

Não estou nem sabendo como procurar para encontrar a solução caso seja um post duplicado, peço desculpas.

Comment: Utilize um programinha muito simples chamado nettimestat, ele corrigi sempre o horário e é MT leve, uso ele na empresa como programa padrão, nunca mais me deu dor de cabeça

Answer (score 1):

As versões iniciais do windows 10 não funcionavam corretamente a sincronização do horário (serviço cliente NTP). Eu baixei na época, 2016, era só dor de cabeça. Fui forçado a usar "nettime".

As versões mais recentes do Windows 10 não apresentam mais esse problema. Usei a 1709, 1809 e, atualmente uso a 1903.